# Set no tab as default active tab on mat tab

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I have search functionality implemented using `mat-tab`, I need no tab selected on initial load.
Tab should get active only when user clicks on specific tab.

Currently, first tab is active on load.
I have tried setting `selectedIndex="null"` but didn't work.
Also, I need reset the selected tab on a button click.

[image: Search using mat tab]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no predefined option in the current API version to deselect all tabs because it's implied that at least one tab should be active. But there is a small workaround (and it seems quite good IMHO): we can add one more auxiliary tab at index `0`, leave it empty (without any content) and hide it with `display: none`. This way you have additional invisible tab, and you still have an option to navigate to this tab, which looks pretty close to deselecting all the tabs.

You can achieve it via just a few rows of HTML / CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<button (click)="tabs.selectedIndex = 0">RESET</button>
<mat-tab-group #tabs>
  <mat-tab></mat-tab> <!-- ADDITIONAL TAB -->
  <mat-tab label="First">
    <p>Content 1</p>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second">
    <p>Content 2</p>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third">
    <p>Content 3</p>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

**CSS:**

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-labels > .mat-tab-label:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

And here is a working [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swpnwy-s9j15u?file=app/tab-group-basic-example.html), you can see it in action.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking on same lines as a work around.

Comment: Based on current AM functionality, it's the best approach I can imagine. Hope it's ok for your case

Answer (score 0):

What I feel is if you do not want to render any of tabs content initially or unitll it has been clicked. you can hide content until tab panel is clicked. Just like below:

.HTML

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabPanelClick($event, $event.tab)">

        <mat-tab label="First-Tab">
          <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="isFirstTabVisible">
          </div>
        </mat-tab>

        <mat-tab label="Second-tab">
          <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="isSecondTabVisible">
          </div>
        </mat-tab>

        <mat-tab label="Third-tab">
          <div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="isThirdTabVisible">
          </div>
        </mat-tab>

</mat-tab-group>
```

.ts

```
onTabPanelClick(event, tab) {
   this.isFirstTabVisible= (event.index === 0) ? true : false;
   this.isSecondTabVisible= (event.index === 1) ? true : false;
   this.isThirdTabVisible= (event.index === 2) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Initially you have to make all tab visibility false. isFirstTabVisible = false, isSecondTabVisible = false and isThirdTabVisible = false

Answer (score -1):

### mat tab active

mat-tab-label-active

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label-active {
  background-color : red;
  font-size : 15px
}
```