# Can I display content of mat-tab only if I click on tab? Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

So I want to display content only if I clicked on tab. Is it possible?
The reason why I want to achieve this is because when I filter through tabs, content is loaded while I'm typing in filter input

Comment: Alright I found this as an solution. Is this good way to achieve this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53818913/10741524

Answer (score 1):

I dont like ::ng-deep, see [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) I always prefer create a class in styles.scss -or in styles.css-

```
.noFirst .mat-tab-labels:first-child > .mat-tab-label:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

Then when I want, add the class to mat-tab-group

```
<mat-tab-group class="noFirst">
  <mat-tab></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="First"> Content 1 </mat-tab>
  ....
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: I do have question in regards to mat table and it seems you have expertise here  can you please help me to resolve this mat table issue?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65347251/how-to-show-split-header-in-the-material-table-having-nested-group-of-data-in-an